# How to do centering for a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there an easy way compute the following array?

```
uc(i,j) = 0.25d0*(u(i,j+1)+u(i+1,j+1)+u(i+1,j)+u(i,j))
```

I tried

```
  from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
  generic_filter(A, np.nanmean, mode='constant', cval=np.nan, size=2)
```

But this does not work. For example

```
   A= np.array([[3, 4, 5],
   [5, 6, 7],
   [7, 8, 9]])
```

then the result of generic filter is:

```
   array([[3, 3, 4],
   [4, 4, 5],
   [6, 6, 7]])
```

I am expecting the first element to be =(3+4+5+6)/4 =4.5

How to do zone averaging in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scipy.ndimage.correlate` (or `scipy.ndimage.convolve`) to filter your image. In the case you describe your kernel would look like this:

```
[[ 0, 0,    0],
 [ 0, 0.25, 0.25],
 [ 0, 0.25, 0.25]]
```

With the center of the kernel being (i, j).

```py
> k = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 0.25, 0.25],[0, 0.25, 0.25]])
> scipy.ndimage.correlate(A.astype(float), k, mode='constant')
array([[4.5 , 5.5 , 3.  ],
       [6.5 , 7.5 , 4.  ],
       [3.75, 4.25, 2.25]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, `A` should be of a float type to do this properly.

When calculating mean, first row/col won't change at all and perhaps should be skipped. With a float A,

```
>>> generic_filter(A, np.nanmean, mode='constant', cval=np.nan, size=2)
array([[3. , 3.5, 4.5],
       [4. , 4.5, 5.5],
       [6. , 6.5, 7.5]])
```

So, `generic_filter(...)[1:, 1:]` is probably what you need.

Another option is to use convolution - it is a bit more flexible, because you can set filter yourself, but you have to create the filter yourself. In this case, the last row/column should be skipped

Example:

```
from scipy.ndimage import convolve
convolution = np.ones((2, 2))/4
convolve(A, convolution)
```